# Unable to figure out the issue with Cygwin aliases

Tags: bash, cygwin, alias

I installed cygwin today on my windows system. I tried to create an alias for my desktop to avoid typing the lengthy command everytime. In the /home/sunde/.bashrc, I inserted the below alias statement and saved it.

`alias DSKP='cd /cygdrive/c/Users/sunde/Desktop'`

Then, I gave `DSKP` command but I am seeing this error **-bash: DSKP: command not found**.

I tried searching the issue but wasn't able to figure out what the issue was. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you start a new shell after you had changed the file?

Comment: Check that the alias is setup by running the command ...alias

Comment: @ChenReddySundeep: There is no such thing as *Cygwin Alias*. You were simply defining a *bash alias*. Did you source .bashrc afterwards? bash is not magic. If you just define the alias in some file, it does not spring into existence automatically in your current shell.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks a lot. Closing and opening it worked. I missed trying the most obvious trick in the book.

Comment: @RamanSailopal After closing it and opening the terminal, I am able to see that the alias is setup.

Comment: @user1934428 I have defined it in the correct file only.

Comment: Then of course it can't work, without starting a new shell. Actually, a new terminal would not be necessary. Just starting a child shell or, of course, sourcing the file would have been sufficient.